# QR decoder that works on mac?

Tags: macos, qr-code, decoder

Anyone know a QR decoder that works on mac or that might be online? I just need to decode one single image.

Comment: The online decoder https://webqr.com/ works fine with no installation, on a saved file or using the camers.  (Discovered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393660/19289))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the most used library [libdecodeqr](http://trac.koka-in.org/libdecodeqr) is depends on OpenCV (gtk2) and it is too hard to compile it on OS X. (Tried to compile it because it is needed by `Image::DecodeQR` perl module - but unsuccessful).

Fortunately, found this link: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=37404 from citing the next:

1. Download the [ZBar source code](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html).
2. Unpack the the tarball, and open the resulting directory in a Terminal window.
3. Type `./configure --disable-video --without-python --without-gtk --without-qt` to configure the build process, limiting dependencies to ImageMagick.
4. Type "make" to invoke the build process.
5. Type "sudo make install", and enter an administrator password when prompted.

You will need `ImageMagick` what can be installed from [macports](http://www.macports.org).

After installing the ZBar, you can nicely decode qrcode with a command

```
zbarimg qrcode_file.png
```

Tested on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 (and Lion/10.7.5)- and works nicely. Becasue it only depends on ImageMagick (exists in macports)- should be easily "compilable" on other OS X versions too.

Answer (score 70):

Using brew, it is easy to install zbar, a QR code reader.

```
brew install zbar
```

Then a QR code can be read by calling:

```
zbarimg qrcode_file.png
```

Also @jm666, [brew can be used to install opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46066903/8524178).

Answer (score 5):

There is an open-source [command line tool named ZBar](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar). It takes a photo as an argument and extracts the information out of any QRCode that it detects in the image.

The open-source project [QR-Reader-Mac](https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/QR-Reader-Mac) provides an Applescript script that acts as a wrapper to `zbar`. You can create a shortcut to the script for processing QRCodes or create a service, as explained below. The script will automatically open the URL contained within the QRCode in your default browser.

### Usage

[image: qrreader]

### Step by step

ZBar can be easily installed with Homebrew:

```
brew install zbar
```

To install QR-Reader-Mac:

1. Open the [QR-Reader-Mac GitHub project page](https://github.com/FrederikRogalski/QR-Reader-Mac), select `Code`, and download the project as a ZIP file:

   [image]
2. Double click the ZIP file to extract it.
3. Double click the workflow you want to install. The following Pop-UP should appear:
4. Confirm by pressing `install`.
5. Open System Preferences and add a shortcut to the open_QRCode service under Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > General:
   [image]

(**Important**: Note that QR-Reader-Mac expects to find the executable 'zbarimg' in `/usr/local/bin/zbarimg`, which is the standard path Homebrew will install it.)

### Copy to Clipboard

The `QRCode2Clipboard.workflow` can be used to extract the content of the QR-Codes into the Clipboard. It can be installed in the same way as the `open_QRCode.workflow`.