# How can I install opencv2 with brew under OSX

Tags: opencv, homebrew

Recently, I installed opencv with the following command:

```
brew install opencv
```

I found opencv3 was installed in dir `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`. But what I want is opencv2. How can install opencv2 with the `brew` command?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The easiest way to find the answer is to use `brew search` to look for available packages. So, in your case:

```
brew search opencv
```

There you will see the package `opencv@2` listed. So, you need:

```
brew install opencv@2
```

Comment: Thanks for your smart answer.

Comment: Pleasure - good luck with your project and remember, questions and answers are free, so come back and ask if you get stuck along the way!

Comment: Wonderful answer and comment! Reminds me of what SO used to be like.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a answer in context of using brew but I can assist you with a  valuable resource that really helped me out when I was first started out with OpenCV that got me up and developing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U49CVY8yOxw

1. Install Xcode , Install C-Make
2. Download OpenCV source code https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.1.0
3. Build and install!

INSTRUCTIONS: Go inside OpenCV once downloaded create new folder called build. Next, open CMake GUI find the directory we just created " build " to build the binaries, Click configure, Select "Unix Makefiles" and use native default compilers. cd into out build directory in our OpenCV folder so something like this /Users/you/Desktop/openCvFolder/build and run the command  "make"   and go have a coffee! I hope this helps it helped me out when I first started experimenting a year ago with OpenCV

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please include an explanation on the solution in the video. Often videos are removed over time and we want to preserve the answer for others to find in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 'brew' stopped supporting downloading outdated package versions. However, if you really need a deprecated version of a package in some cases you may try to find it's formula on git/homebrew and manually install it.

For example this is a formula for 'opencv@2':
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/5dfd4d4d69cc70e496f9b46801c96a66f4b008eb/Formula/opencv%402.rb

But in case of 'opencv2' this will be very problematic, because the package requires 'python v2' and another outdated package 'numpy@1.16'. After that even if you'll manage to install all three packages from their formulas brew just won't be able to create correct symlinks between them...

Thus last time when I found a package that was depended on opencv@2 I found that it was far easier to make changes in the package C++ functions and make the package work with opencv v4.x (most recent one). Despite that I'm purely Python developer still this proved to be faster. OpenCV code doesn't change a lot, so most probably you will need to fix imports in the C++ / python code.